# How do i customize my buttons?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, mfc, sdi

I'm new to MFC, 
How can I customize buttons in such a way that

1. It should be painted  in background.
2. Should be able to place a image on painted area and
3. Should add text on painted area.

After browsing the internet I got to know that we need to override DrawItem method once the button is created with BS_OWNERDRAW style,
How can i override DrawItem Method?

( MFC application using SDI,)

Comment: You override `DrawItem` in the same way you override any other class member in C++. I'm not sure, whether this is the question you meant to ask.

Answer (score 1):

In Global Variable:

```
CButton button;
```

In DoDataExchange:

```
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BUTTON, button);
```

where IDC_button is declared on your dialog resource and pDX is your CDataExchange

Where you want to add image:

```
button.SetBitmap((HBITMAP)LoadImage(AfxGetApp()->m_hInstance,
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1),
        IMAGE_BITMAP, 16, 16, LR_COLOR));
```

where m_hInstance is your CWinApp, IDB_BITMAP1 is a resource picture.

For text:

```
  button.SetWindowTextW(_T("TEXT"));
```

Comment: Background should be painted with some solid colors,before adding image/text. How can i do that ?

Comment: no it's for dlg based application, I'm asking for SDI